How to config Google Batch job that uses an accelerator, and run in docker image from Artifact Registry
Cloud logging reveals that I am getting two errors in succession:

Unable to find image 'australia-southeast1-docker.pkg.dev/<project_id>/staging_repo/defect-detection-hd-received:latest' locally


Head "https://australia-southeast1-docker.pkg.dev/v2/<project_id>/staging_repo/defect-detection-hd-received/manifests/latest": denied: Unauthenticated request. Unauthenticated requests do not have permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" on resource "projects/<project_id>/locations/australia-southeast1/repositories/staging_repo" (or it may not exist).

I've double-checked the container.imageUri path is correctly addressing the docker container in Google Artifact Registry.
I've used a job.json file as follows:
{
  "taskGroups": [
    {
      "taskSpec": {
        "runnables": [
          {
            "container": {
              "imageUri": "australia-southeast1-docker.pkg.dev/<project_id>/staging_repo/defect-detection-hd-received:latest",
              "options": "-e STAGING=true -e CLOUD_RUN=true",
            }
          }
        ],
      "compute_resource": {
        "cpu_milli": 1000,
        "memory_mib": 16000
      },
      "volumes": [
        {
          "gcs": {
            "remotePath": "racas_ai_model_staging"
          },
          "mountPath": "/mnt/disks/share"
        }
      ],
      "max_run_duration": {
        "seconds": 180
      },
      "max_retry_count": 1
    },
    "task_count": 1,
    "parallelism": 1
  }
  ],
  "allocation_policy": {
    "instances": [{
      "installGpuDrivers": true,
      "policy": {
        "machine_type": "n1-standard-1",
        "provisioning_model": "SPOT",
        "accelerators": [
            {
              "type": "nvidia-tesla-p4",
              "count": 1
            }
          ]
      }
    }],
    "location": {
      "allowedLocations": [
        "regions/australia-southeast1"
      ]
    },
    "serviceAccount": {
      "email": "batcher-sa@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    }
  },
  "labels": {
    "key": "env",
    "value": "testing"
  },
  "logs_policy": {
    "destination": "CLOUD_LOGGING"
  }
}

I run the job using the following script:
gcloud auth login
gcloud config set project <project_id>
gcloud services enable batch.googleapis.com compute.googleapis.com logging.googleapis.com
gcloud batch jobs submit test-batcher \
    --config=job.json \
    --location=australia-southeast1

The batch job also needs to download images from a bucket, and write object detection results to Firestore. The "batcher-sa" service account was generated using this script (prior to submitting the batch job. I am a project owner. Permission on the service account have been confirmed to via cloud Console):
gcloud auth login

# STAGING
gcloud config set project <project_id>

# Create the service account
gcloud iam service-accounts create batcher-sa \
    --description="Service account for reading Artifact Registry, reading Storage, logging," \
    --display-name="Batch SA" \
    --project=<project_id>

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <project_id> \
    --member="serviceAccount:batcher-sa@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --role="roles/batch.jobsEditor"

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <project_id> \
    --member="serviceAccount:batcher-sa@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --role="roles/storage.objectViewer"

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <project_id> \
    --member="serviceAccount:batcher-sa@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --role="roles/serviceAccountUser"

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <project_id> \
    --member="serviceAccount:batcher-sa@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --role="roles/artifactregistry.reader"

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <project_id> \
    --member="serviceAccount:batcher-sa@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --role="roles/artifactregistry.serviceAgent"

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <project_id> \
    --member="serviceAccount:batcher-sa@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --role="roles/logging.logWriter"

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <project_id> \
    --member="serviceAccount:batcher-sa@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --role="roles/datastore.user"

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <project_id> \
    --member="serviceAccount:batcher-sa@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
    --role="roles/batch.agentReporter"

The only think I can mistake I can think of is not specifying readonly for the mount for storage, and perhaps the Artifact Registry.
What is my next step?
